# How to restyle wpf window like Blu twitter client

Tags: wpf

for a long time i am looking for trick to develop a Blu like window where some leaf image is coming out from title bar. how they design such layout.

here is small image of custom title bar
[image]

please some one tell me how could i design this type of title bar where something coming out from title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting an appropriate background image for the window and setting `AllowsTransparency` to `True`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/bg.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
```

Then you have to create your own title bar, because the default one will not be displayed.